# Fiddler Marker (COMMENT) doesn't have timestamp

Tags: timestamp, comments, fiddler, marker

Using Fiddler when adding a comment (using fiddler/fiddlerCup) the comment doesn't have a timestamp.
The time I am taking is request begin (because this is the time displayed in the chart and for all other requests)
This is an important data since I instruct the user to add button when action finished for him (including rendering time) and since the comment has no timestamp, it worth nothing.

Think it should be fixed in program, but will appreciate if someone can instruct how to solve it using "Rules"
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How, specifically, are you creating a marker? In Fiddler, hitting either `=` or `Shift+M` in the Web Sessions list creates a marker with an embedded timestamp.

FiddlerCap doesn't currently add timestamps, but I will fix that for the next build.

Comment: Well, many times, Since I perform tests that involve client interaction, I want to measure The full operation. BTW, the timestamp is better be added in  the time that the button was clicked and not the time the OK was clicked. since it takes some time to write the comment. Thanks